# Selenium Date Format

Tags: selenium

I'm pulling data with selenium and saving this data to the database. Although the relevant column in the database is date and the field is filled in the relevant site, the database is empty, as '0000-00-00'

The code for the area I'm scraping.

```
if "Test" in description_list:
            index_no = description_list.index("Test")
            try:
                first_registration = value_list[index_no]
            except:
                first_registration =
```

> An example of the date I am trying to engrave; 07/28. I appreciate your help.

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import QName
import bs4
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import E
import pymysql
import mysql.connector
import configparser
import re
import numpy as np
import time
import concurrent.futures
# import erequests
# import lxml
from multiprocessing import Pool
# from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
from multiprocessing import Process
from datetime import datetime
from tqdm import tqdm  # progress bar
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
   host="localhost",
   user="root",
   password="",
   database="m_n"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "SELECT ad_link FROM adlinks_d"

mycursor.execute(sql)

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
all_links = myresult[0:]
len_all_links = len(all_links)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(all_links, columns=['links'])

x = 1
y = 5

#def fonksiyon(i):

#    global x
#    global y

number = np.arange(x,y)

for i in tqdm(number):
   ad_link = dataframe.links[i]
   fireFoxOptions = Options()
   fireFoxOptions.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe'
   fireFoxOptions.add_argument("--headless")
   fireFoxOptions.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
   fireFoxOptions.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
   driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=fireFoxOptions)
   sleep_time = 1

   driver.get(ad_link)
   time.sleep(sleep_time)
   ad_source = driver.page_source
   ad_soup = BeautifulSoup(ad_source, 'html.parser')

   mainresults = ad_soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'cBox cBox--content u-overflow-inherit '})

   cars_data = pd.DataFrame({
       'brand_and_model': brand_and_model,
       'model_version': model_version,
   },
       index=[0])
 
   df3 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(equipment_key, equipment_value)), columns=['all_key', 'all_value'])

   df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(all_key, all_value)), columns=['all_key', 'all_value'])
   
   df1.insert(0, "brand_and_model", brand_and_model)

   df2_3 = pd.concat([df2, df3])
   df2_3 = df2_3.set_index('all_key').T.reset_index(drop=True)
   df2_3 = df2_3.rename_axis(None, axis=1)

   df_last = pd.concat([df1, df2_3], axis=1)

   df_last = df_last.astype(str).groupby(df_last.columns, sort=False, axis=1).agg(
       lambda x: x.apply(','.join, 1))  

   now = datetime.now()
   datetime_string = str(now.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"))

   df_last['download_date_time'] = datetime_string

   config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
   config.read(filenames='my.properties')

   scrap_db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', database='m_n', charset='utf8mb4',
                              cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

   cursor = scrap_db.cursor()

   sql = """CREATE TABLE S(
       brand_and_model VARCHAR(32),
       first_registration DATE(6),
       download_date_time DATE(6)
       )"""

   #cursor.execute(sql)

   for row_count in range(0, df_last.shape[0]):
       chunk = df_last.iloc[row_count:row_count + 1, :].values.tolist()

       brand_and_model = ""
       first_registration = ""
      
       download_date_time = ""

       lenght_of_chunk = len(chunk[0])

       if "brand_and_model" in cars_data:
           try:
               brand_and_model = chunk[0][0]
           except:
               brand_and_model = ""

       if chunk[0][lenght_of_chunk - 1] != "":
           download_date_time = chunk[0][lenght_of_chunk - 1]

   if (brand_and_model == ' '):
       control = "false"
   else:
       control = "true"

   if control == "true":
       mySql_insert_query = "INSERT INTO S (brand_and_model,first_registration,download_date_time) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
       val = (
           brand_and_model, location, first_registration, download_date_time)

       cursor = scrap_db.cursor()
       cursor.execute(mySql_insert_query, val)
       scrap_db.commit()
       print(cursor.rowcount, "Record inserted successfully into *S* table")
   driver.close()
```

Comment: Could you post more code? Actually we do not know what your code is doing with only that piece

Comment: Off course, adding